# Problem running webpy Hello World demo

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to run the hello world demo from the official web site:

```
import web

urls = ('/.*', 'index')
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:  
    def GET(self):   
        return 'Hello,world......'

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr = None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)  
    app.run()
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
 File "E:\Text-1.py", line 15, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "D:\tool\EPD\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 316, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
  File "E:\Text-1.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr = None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)
  File "D:\tool\EPD\lib\site-packages\web\wsgi.py", line 17, in runfcgi
    return flups.WSGIServer(func, multiplexed=True, bindAddress=addr).run()
  File "D:\tool\EPD\lib\site-packages\flup-1.0.3.dev_20110111-py2.6.egg\flup\server\fcgi.py", line 112, in run
    sock = self._setupSocket()
  File "D:\tool\EPD\lib\site-packages\flup-1.0.3.dev_20110111-py2.6.egg\flup\server\fcgi_base.py", line 1020, in _setupSocket
    'If you want FCGI, please create an external FCGI server '
ValueError: If you want FCGI, please create an external FCGI server by providing a valid bindAddress. If you want CGI, please force CGI operation. Use FCGI_FORCE_CGI=Y environment or forceCGI parameter.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I've formatted the question to be easier to read.  It didn't look like you changed the code or the error so I reverted it back.  If you do make changes, please keep the formatting so it's easier for us to read.

Comment: sorry,i got trouble with the formating right now, i have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that helps, but I just commented out this line:

`web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr = None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)`

It runs ok.

Comment: en... i've rechecked my code,i added the line "web.wsgi.runwsgi= ...." by mistake,now it works,thank you,Asterisk